# Conflict with server-side and client-side validation

Tags: javascript, validation, coldfusion, server-side, coldfusion-11

I'm working in a ColdFusion 11 environment. I want to make a form, that when submitted, validates whether the value I'm entering is already in the database. I think I'm mixing up server-side and client-side and that is the cause of the problem.

query :

```
<cfquery name="FindIdMailExist" datasource="#application.zips_database#" username="#application.zips_username#" password="#application.zips_password#">
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE user_name = '#userName#'
</cfquery>
```

My javascript (client-side) + some CF code (server-side) :

```
   <script>
    function CheckSub()
    {
        alert("submited");
        return true;
    }
    function checkName(formObject, formField, fieldValue)
    {
        <cfoutput>
        alert('#FindIdMailExist.RecordCount#');
        </cfoutput>

        return true;
    }
  <script>
```

My form :

```
<cfform  onsubmit="CheckSub()" name="form">
    <br>
<table>
  <tr><td width="120" align="right">Name:</td><td><cfinput name="userName"type="text" onvalidate="checkName" message="pas  email"></td></tr>
  <tr><td><cfinput name="Submit" type="submit" value="Register"></td></tr>

</table>

</cfform>
```

So everything is working well expect for one thing. If you understand the code, an alert is displayed with the result of 1 or 0. 1 = yes the database already contains this name. 0 = no, the database doesn't already have it. The problem is when I click submit the result is 1 submit later.

example :

- Enter an already existing name and click submit : result = 0 (wrong one)
- Enter nothing : result 1 (the result is always the one I submitted before)

So maybe it impossible to validate server side before submitting the form?
I want to make sure everything is good before sending my form to add the data to the database. I want to do this server-side for the safety.

Can anyone suggest a better way?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you can use ajax to do this easily. Why not ajax?

Comment: Hummm you think if i use ajax everything gonna be synchronise whit no delay ? let me try it! :D thx for the tips ... if u want u can give me an exemple ... thank a lot

Comment: On the client, you can take it one step further by not including a submit button until the data passes muster (not blank, not in db).

Comment: No matter what you do on the client-side you still need to validate on the server-side. Always.

Comment: In terms of UX, validating via ajax is a good idea. However, as @Miguel-F said, you still need to *re-validate* once the form is submitted. Never assume anything about user supplied input. It should always be validated.

Answer (score -1):

Try with the below code and function:
Keep the **FindIdMailExist.RecordCount** in a hidden field:

```
<cfoutput>
   <input type="hidden" name="hdnFindIdMailExist" 
        id="hdnFindIdMailExist" value="#FindIdMailExist.RecordCount#">
</cfoutput>
```

Now the above field will be in the form when clicking on submit. Try to modify the function in below way

```
function checkName(formObject, formField, fieldValue)
    {
        var testid = document.getElementById('hdnFindIdMailExist').val();
        alert(testid);
        return true;
    }
```

Took a variable and assigned the variable with the form element value and gave an alert. It is not a good practice to keep `<cfoutput>` in the javascript which may not sometimes access. Secondly it will not accept ## symbols in alert.

Comment: That will not make a difference because the result of the query still is not known until *after* the value is entered and the form submitted (which is what they are trying to avoid). The only way to achieve this - without submitting the form - is to make a second request back to the server with ajax.